# Call to method in closure requires explicit self

Tags: swift, swift3

I have this code:

```
let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
        (
        data, response, error) in

        guard let _:Data = data, let _:URLResponse = response  , error == nil else {
            print("error")
            return
        }

        let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        result = dataString as? String ?? ""
        print("Data received is: " + result)

        if (result == "failed") {
            displayAlertMessage(userMessage: "Your credentials are incorrect. Please check your email and password.") //ERROR
            //ERROR ^
            print("Cannot login.")
        } else {

            // Store the userID for local use
            let userID = result
            UserDefaults.standard.set(userID, forKey:"userID")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

            // Since login is successful, proceed to Prime page
            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToPrimePage", sender: self)
            }
            print("Can login.")
        }
    })
```

The error keeps telling me to add self. to that error line. but after adding self., the program crashes with the message

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] may only be called from the main thread.'

I'm very new to swift so I might not understand a lot of the terms used.

Comment: Update your question with details about the crash. Include the complete error message and point out the exact line causing the crash.

Comment: Needless to say, adding `self.` is not the cause of the crash. Most likely, `displayAlertMessage` is interacting with the UI, which must be done on the main thread. The `URLSession` completion handler closure is not run on the main thread. Make sure to dispatch that to the main queue, just like you did with the segue.

Comment: @rmaddy I have a comment on that line where the error appeared. I just added the error message

Comment: Micah's answer, which was deleted at rmaddy's prompting, is likely correct. `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.displayAlertMessage(...) }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add self and make sure you hop back on the main thread before you display any alert message to the user.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async() {
    self.displayAlertMessage(userMessage: "Your credentials are incorrect. Please check your email and password.")
}
```

Comment: Since the question posts no information about the actual problem, posting an answer seems a bit premature. Wait until you know what the actual problem is.

Comment: I agree, it was a bit premature to guess this was the problem given the lack of clarity in the original question, but as the question was clarified, it turns out that this was actually correct. Frankly, given the code snippet, it was one of the few things that could of caused a crash.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to Rob's comment on a deleted solution, but this worked:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async() {
    self.displayAlertMessage(userMessage: "Your credentials are incorrect. Please check your email and password.")
}
```

Not sure how or why though, thanks "Micah".

Comment: There were two completely separate problems in the original code. First, you were missing `self.` which was preventing the code from compiling. Second, this code in the `dataTask` completion handler closure is running on a background thread, but you _must_ do UI updates on the main thread (just as your error message says). So, the above dispatches the displaying of the alert message to the main queue (i.e. runs it on the main thread).

Comment: Sorry for deleting. I thought I would wait a bit for more information. I have since undated if you want to mark it as the answer. Like Rob said all UI updates need to be done on the main thread that was causing the crash. And the lack of self was keeping it from compiling.